# How to do stepwise regression in r for more independent variables and less observations?

Tags: r, regression

I'm trying to do stepwise regression for following data:

```
y <- c(1.2748, 1.2574, 1.5571, 1.4178, 0.8491, 1.3606, 1.4747, 1.3177, 1.2896, 0.8453)
x <- data.frame(A = c(2,3,4,5,6,2,3,4,5,6), 
                B = c(2,4,1,3,5,1,3,5,2,4)*100, 
                C = c(9,5,11,5,11,7,13,7,13,9), 
                D = c(6,5,3,7,6,4,3,7,5,4), 
                E = c(1,1,0.8,0.8,0.6,0.6,0.4,0.4,0.2,0.2))
x$A2 <- x$A^2
x$B2 <- x$B^2
x$C2 <- x$C^2
x$D2 <- x$D^2
x$E2 <- x$E^2
x$AB <- x$A*x$B
```

As we can see, it has 10 observations and 11 independent variables so I can't build a linear regression model for it. In fact, only a few factors is useful and in this case, I need to use stepwise regression and "forward" to add independent variables into my formula. But stats:: step function cannot be used. I wonder if there is a method to do it. I know there is a package called "StepReg" but I don't fully understand how to use it and how to read the results. Thank you!

Comment: Standard linear regression cannot be estimated uniquely If you have more predictors than observations. For such a problem I'd look at penalised regression; ridge or lasso.  However, if your real data only has 10 observations I would likely rethink my analysis. Consider what hypothesis you are most interested in and maybe run, for example, a few bivariate models. I'd be very cautious over any conclusions

Answer (score 1):

I just run stepwise regression with the data you provided using R package **StepReg**

Here is the code, and hope this can help you.

```
library(StepReg)
df <- data.frame(y,x)
# forward method with information criterion 'AIC', you can choose other information criterion
stepwise(df, y="y", exclude=NULL, include=NULL, Class=NULL,
         selection="forward", select="AIC")

# forward method with significant levels, significant level for entry = 0.15
stepwise(df, y="y", exclude=NULL, include=NULL, Class=NULL,
         selection="forward", select="SL",sle=0.15)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `olsrr` package which gives similar results as that of SPSS. Here is the solution

```
library(olsrr)
df <- data.frame(y, x)
model <- lm(y ~ ., data = df)
smlr <- ols_step_both_p(model, pent = 0.05, prem = 0.1) #pent p value; variables with p value less than pent will enter into the model.
#premp value; variables with p more than prem will be removed from the model.
```

You can get the model details by calling

```
smlr
smlr$model
smlr$beta_pval #regression coefficients with p-values
```

I have kept the values of `pent` and `prem` same as the default values used by SPSS.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this function. However, it operates with warning:
  "In anova.lm(fullmodel) :
  ANOVA F-tests on an essentially perfect fit are unreliable"
  I guess it's because there is no degree of freedom of residuals. In this case, is the model reliable?

Comment: I do not agree with the comment at all "*Warnings do not matter*". As the estimated  model is not unique (coefficients set to NA based on some software dependent rule) , and some, (or all in this case) standard errors not estimated it cannot be used for inference. It will massively overfit and so should not be used for prediction. Really the only advice should be "*don't do that*"